# DataTable.Select() with row value having white space

Tags: c#, datatable

How to resolve, compare a value having white space in DataTable?

I tried as

```
 string str= "A B C";

 DataRow[] foundRows;
 foundRows = datatable1.Select("a= '" + str + "'");
```

in my datatable colum 'a' havingg data as

```
 A B C        
 A B D   
 ACD                  
       AB C
```

without space it is working but space it is not working.please resolve my problem
Thanks in advance

Here `A B C` and `AB C` both are different

Comment: Is `A B D` a matching record? You havent explained your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use LINQ? First i would remove the sapces from the search-string:

```
str = str.Replace(" ", "");
foundRows = datatable1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("a").Split().Contains(str))
    .ToArray();
```

if you instead want to ignore the spaces:

```
foundRows = datatable1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<string>("a").Replace(" ", "") == str)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you should `str.Replace(" ", "")` too, if the input is `"A B C";`

Comment: @mybirthname: to be honest,i don't know possible inputs and how they should be treated. But OP should now know how to modofiy the query to get the expected result.

Comment: Yes your solution is better.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: what is the assembly reference for AsEnumerable?

Comment: @shafi7468: you need `using System.Linq;` and a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` (for [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @TimSchmelter: if  column  'a' having 1) AB C   2) A B C then your soultion gives row count 2 . But in my situation AB C ,A B C both are different.How can i resolve this,Please help me